# Facing issues while Uploading a cookbook to private Supermarket

Tags: chef-infra

I have installed the Supermarket and Chef servers.
Now I am trying to upload the cookbook from my local machine by running a knife command .
I have configured my knife.rb according to this document .
https://docs.chef.io/supermarket.html

```
knife supermarket share c1-supermarket-master "other"
Generating metadata for c1-supermarket-master from /var/folders/6s/vb0m1sqd1hldg7thk6m3dflmv7dc2h/T/chef-c1-supermarket-master-build20150624-23977-1n8kp0n/c1-supermarket-master/metadata.rb
Making tarball c1-supermarket-master.tgz
ERROR: Error uploading cookbook c1-supermarket-master to the Opscode Cookbook Site: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed. Increase log verbosity (-VV) for more information.
```

I have run

```
knife ssl fetch https://ip-10-94-165-251/ -c knife.rb
```

and then

```
knife ssl check https://ip-10-94-165-251/ -c knife.rb
```

Comment: Get your certificate from the trusted cert directory and paste it at end of chef cacert.pem. The trusted cert directory seems to be used only for API calls. `cat /etc/chef/trusted_cert/You_server_.pem >> /opt/chef/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai , by "You_server_.pem" you mean my chef or supermarket server that I have installed ?, or you are talking about the server cert from where I am running . Currently I am trying this from my local mac machine.

Comment: The supermarket certificate

Comment: now I am getting a different error : `Authentication failed due to an invalid public/private key pair. If you have changed your keys recently try logging out and logging back in to Supermarket.`

Comment: I have reset the key again and mentioned them in the knife.rb like this : `client_key               "#{current_dir}/ishugupta_supermarket.pem"`  and `validation_key           "#{current_dir}/org_name-validator.pem"`

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of knowledge there, not using supermarket, I can just help on the SSL part. Edit your question to update it for the current problem

Answer (score 0):

The knife.rb wasnt configured properly with the correct chef server url and supermarket url.